# How to add one more planet? html5 css3 animation

Tags: html, css

I found this [SOLUTION](https://www.useragentman.com/blog/2013/03/03/animating-circular-paths-using-css3-transitions/) but how would I add one more 
like this?
[image]

```
        .saturn {

            position: absolute;
            left: 315px;
            top: 143px;

            -webkit-animation: myOrbit 4s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Safari 5 */
               -moz-animation: myOrbit 4s linear infinite; /* Firefox 5-15 */
                 -o-animation: myOrbit 4s linear infinite; /* Opera 12+ */
                    animation: myOrbit 4s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Firefox 16+, 
                                                              IE 10+, Safari 5 */   
        }
        @keyframes myOrbit {
            from { transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(150px) rotate(0deg); }
            to   { transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(150px) rotate(-360deg); }
        }
    .animation_delay_1{
        animation-delay: 3s;
    }

     <div class="logo_carousel">
                            <img id="logo_center"src="logo.png">
                            <img class="saturn" src="logo1.png">
    <img class="saturn animation_delay_1" src="logo2.png">
</div>
```

I tried to add `animation-delay`, But this is not quite what I need. The logo just starts spinning later, but I need it to spin immediately but from a different position.

Comment: What you have tried so far? Where is the code?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.saturn {
  position: absolute;
  left: 315px;
  top: 143px;
  -webkit-animation: myOrbit 4s linear infinite;
  /* Chrome, Safari 5 */
  -moz-animation: myOrbit 4s linear infinite;
  /* Firefox 5-15 */
  -o-animation: myOrbit 4s linear infinite;
  /* Opera 12+ */
  animation: myOrbit 4s linear infinite;
  /* Chrome, Firefox 16+, 
                                                              IE 10+, Safari 5 */
}

@keyframes myOrbit {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(150px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(150px) rotate(-360deg);
  }
}

.animation_delay_1 {
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

.animation_delay_3 {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo_carousel">
  <img id="logo_center" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLMDq.jpg?s=48&g=1">
  <img class="saturn animation_delay_1" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLMDq.jpg?s=48&g=1">
  <img class="saturn animation_delay_2" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLMDq.jpg?s=48&g=1">
  <img class="saturn animation_delay_1" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLMDq.jpg?s=48&g=1">
</div>
```

You would add another image with a new animation class:

```
<img class="saturn animation_delay_3" src="logo2.png">
```

Then add a new animation CSS with a new delay such as 4s.

```
    .animation_delay_3{
        animation-delay: 4s;
    }
```

Results: https://codepen.io/MistaPrime/pen/YzzXeNJ

Comment: this is not quite what I need. Pictures should begin to rotate simultaneously and not after 4 seconds but not at one point.

Comment: I edited the codepen, you can now change the 4s to 0.5 or 0.7.

Comment: is not what I need. Initially, the picture is centered and only after 0.5s where necessary. And I need her to be there right away and not after 0.5

Comment: Then reduce it to a milisecond such as 0.1. That's pretty much how long it takes for your browser to open.